# How to refresh browse from thread ? C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, browser, web, refresh

I have an application that populates a grid with information from a SELECT. After all the filling, I gather a playlist (songs) and reproduce in the same sequence. After this whole process, I need to run it again. I've used the TimerPicker LOAD_PAGE to give a 1 in 1 minute, but can not run from time to time. I need to force a page_load at the end of execution of the process.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
        Thread thrPlayMusic = new Thread(ThreadPlayMusic);
        thrPlayMusic.Start();
    }

  public void ThreadPlayMusic()
    {
        music.PlaySound();

    }
```

My application is ASP.NET.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)` or `Server.Transfer()` to "refresh" the page.

So for your case, use `join`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thrPlayMusic.Start();
    thrPlayMusic.Join();
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
}
```

Comment: This does not work. When I use the JOIN, it runs my second action plan first, keeping my page on LOAD.